# Segfault and uninitialized data when generating a random array in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define len 10

int *randomArray(void);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int *rArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
    rArray = randomArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(rArray+i));
    }
    puts("");
    free(rArray);
}

int *randomArray(void)
{
    int array[len] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % len;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Task is to create an array of `int`s and have a function fill that array with random numbers. The function `randomArray()` works just fine, but for some reason the assignment `rArray = randomArray()` doesn't work correctly, although some elements of `rArray` are valid numbers not gibberish. Also, the last main line `free(rArray);` crashes the program which is just mind numbing for me, it doesn't make any sense. If I remove the line the program doesn't crash but we all know you need to `free()` a `malloc()`-ed array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem here is, `array` is a local variable in the `randomArray()` function scope. Once the function returns, the returned address becomes ***invalid***. Any further attempt to use the memory will lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Moreover, from your approach, you are trying to overwrite the allocated memory by the address being returned from the function call, which will cause memory leak. Rather, change your design, pass the allocated memory to the function as the argument and just fill the elements using the `rand()` call.

Answer (score 1):

The `randomArray` return a pointer to the first element of the ***local array*** `array`.

That pointer becomes invalid immediately once the function returns as the variable goes out of scope. Using it in any way will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What makes it even worse is that you *reassign* the pointer `rArray`, making you lose the original memory you allocated. That means your call to `free` *again* will lead to UB.

To solve both problems, pass the pointer and the size as arguments to the `randomArray` function:

```
void randomArray(int *array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % size;
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but in this case, passing size would be redundant, as it is defined as a MACRO already. Just saying.

Comment: @SouravGhosh When passing a pointer to an "array" it's always a good habit to pass the size of it as well. The size might not always be available as a macro. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int *randomArray(void)
{
    int array[len] = { 0 };
    //...
    return array;
 }
```

`array` goes out of scope at `}` and accessing this returned pointer is UB.
Moreover `rArray = randomArray();` leaks memory since now you cannot free the malloc'd memory. You should pass the `rArray` to a function, which will be responsible for filing it.

Answer (score 0):

In randomArray() function, you are returning the array that is allocated on stack.  That array will be freed when returning from randomArray() function.  Instead, you can do this:

```
void randomArray(int * array)
{
    // Remove this int array[len] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % len;
    }
    // Remove this .. return array;
}
```

And call randomArray(rArray) from main()